# How to upload Files to Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-sql

I have a Google Cloud Endpoints wich is using Cloud SQL to store data. I want to provide a file upload for Clients and the files should be stored in Cloud Storage but I also want to store file meta data and the file storage url in Cloud SQL.

What's the best was to do this?

Can I upload files through cloud endpoints or do I need an extra upload Servlet?

How can I update my database entities which needs a reference to the uploaded files.

Any examples on how to combine those 3 technologies?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your clients are not added to your google cloud project (which is typically the case), your users don't have write access to your GCS bucket. You can either  submit files to your application and move to GCS from there (not recommended as consumes more network and CPU) or a better way is to submit to GCS directly.

To let the client write to your GCS bucket directly, you will need to either:
1. put your access key on client for write access (not recommended), if the client is used by limited trusted people.
2. generate a time-bound token and put it on the client as signed URL to upload directly.

Endpoints APIs themselves cannot do this, but you can generate the signed GCS URL at the server and get it using endpoints on client. then set it as form action (on web client, other clients have similar ways for signed upload) and submit the form to upload the file.

```
<form action="SIGNED_URL_FROM_ENDPOINTS" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I don't see an open-source code out there doing exactly this, but closest is [this project that does generate the signed URL with a time-out (the only unintuitive part)](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-photo-sharing-demo-java).

Best way to update the metadata in your database is to [watch GCS bucket using 'Object Change Notifications'](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Watching). Another way is to send the metadata to your server from client itself, which can be an endpoints call. You can also use a mix of both where the metadata goes to server using endpoints even before the the file is uploaded and the notification updates the record with confirmation that it is available to serve.